# jbpm 7 rest api query task instances with additional parameter groups

Tags: jbpm, kie

So what I want to do is to show tasks belonging to certain user group assigned to the task..

[image]

According to the [doc(jbpm 6.4)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/development_guide/realtime_decision_server#querying_tasks) from Redhat regarding querying task instances, I can use additional parameters: status, groups and user. I tried to use "groups". I thought it means "user group" assigned to the user task. ([the 7.1 docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.1.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/) doesn't even have relevant information)

Adding parameter "status" ( ?status=Completed ) works, but "groups" has no effect on the result data set. I don't know why. Has the new version changed or the parameter itself need to be formatted or there is group ID instead of strings.

Here is the doc:

> 16.6. QUERYING TASKS
>
> Use the following entry point:
>   http://SERVER:PORT/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/. To use
>   pagination, use the page and pageSize parameters. The following list
>   of endpoints contains additional parameters, if applicable:
>
> [GET] tasks/instances/pot-owners Returns a list of tasks where the
>   actual user is defined as a potential owner.
>
> Additional parameters you can use: status, groups, user.
>
> Note that the user filter is applicable only when the request is sent
>   without authentication.

My query is like:

```
http://SERVER:PORT/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/tasks/instances/pot-owners?groups=trainers
```

I also tried to dig into the source code, but I failed:

https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/tree/f70a465dd2621f5598f043631b8eb991142e05ba/jbpm-services/jbpm-kie-services/src/main/java/org/jbpm/kie/services/impl

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I'm also trying to get the list of tasks by using a user group name

Comment: Long time ago. I'll try to explain. This group basically is given up. I used different user with different name and password in jbpm. Then my app treat each user like a "group user" and all my app users will take this "group user" as their group. So I just mapped it on my server side before I query kie server for authorization.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Aha! I also experimented with assigning tasks to "users" with names of the groups I use. Seems to work fine for what I need. Thanks again!